# Wrong Wolfram Alpha limit? $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{{xy^3}}{{x^2+y^6}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Wolfram Alpha gives me: $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \dfrac{{xy^3}}{{x^2+y^6}}=0$.

I assume $f\left( {x,y} \right) = \dfrac{{x{y^3}}}{{{x^2} + {y^6}}}$

I find that when $x=y^3$, $f\left( {x,y} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2}$, while when $x=0, f\left( {x,y} \right) = 0$. Hence the limit does not exist.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You are correct, but how do you enter this into wolfram alpha? It could be good to provide a link.

Comment: (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(x+y%5E3)%2F(x%5E2+%2B+y%5E6)+as+%7Bx,y%7D-%3E+%7B0,0%7D)  It seems that the particular path along the x-axis is default?

Comment: I also see "Standard computation time exceeded...", maybe this explains the wrong result.

Comment: i think the limit does not exist

Comment: @mickep This is the link I entered http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+limit+_%7B(x,y)-%3E(0,0)%7D(xy%5E(3))%2F(x%5E(2)%2By%5E(6))

Comment: A general recommendation: use plot-command instead.

Comment: See also: [Evaluating $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{(xy)^3}{x^2+y^6}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1024178). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim%5Climits_%7B(x%2Cy)%5Cto(0%2C0)%7D%5Cfrac%7B%7Bxy%5E3%7D%7D%7B%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E6%7D%7D%24&p=1). I am not sure whether this is question about the limit (in which case it is a duplicate) or whether it is more about WolframAlpha (in which case the tag ([tag:wolfram-alpha]) should be used).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2053081/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Mathematica*, and consequently WolframAlpha, does not have built-in capability to evaluate arbitrary multivariate limits.  Therefore, the command

```
Limit[x y/(x^2 + y^2), x -> 0]
```

gives $0$, but

```
Limit[x y/(x^2 + y^2) /. x -> y, {y -> 0}]
```

yields $1/2$.  The path-dependence of the limit can only be handled when a path is specified.  This is something that many users of WolframAlpha misunderstand about `Limit`.  If you write

```
Limit[x y/(x^2 + y^2), {x -> 0, y -> 0}]
```

*Mathematica* will simply thread `Limit[]` over the list of replacement rules `{x -> 0, y -> 0}`, producing the output $\{0,0\}$.  To get a better understanding of what it's doing, try the command

```
Limit[x y/(x^2 + y^2), {x -> 1, y -> 2, x -> 3}]
```

Clearly, it doesn't behave the way one might *think* it should behave.  And if you think you can write

```
Limit[x y/(x^2 + y^2), {x,y} -> {0,0}]
```

you get an error, because `{x,y}` is not a valid variable for `Limit`.  This error definitely shows that such multivariate limits are not within the scope of *Mathematica*'s functionality.

---

Now, that doesn't mean that WolframAlpha can't be a bit smarter than *Mathematica*'s built in `Limit`:  if you enter

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit+of+x+y%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E2)+as+(x,y)+tends+to+(0,0)

You will get the proper response, but if you enter

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit+of+x+y%5E3%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E6)+as+(x,y)+tends+to+(0,0)

you get a wrong response, because again, WolframAlpha is built on *Mathematica*'s functionality.  While it can handle some special queries, I suspect that these are probably pre-programmed somehow, or that they were special (but common) queries that were added to the knowledge base.  In any case, I would not rely on WolframAlpha or *Mathematica* to handle multivariate limits.

Comment: On the other hand, Maple does attempt to compute actual multivariate limits.  In this case, **limit(x*y^3/(x^2+y^6),{x=0,y=0});** returns $undefined$.

Comment: In version 11.2 released September 2017, Mathematica added support for multivariate limits and handles this correctly. But at the time of writing, Wolfram|Alpha gets related limits like `Limit[x*y^3/(x^3+y^3),{x,y}->{0,0}]` wrong.