# Multivariable limit solving: is it Wolfram or me?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

We want to calculate the following limit:

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$$

I have expressed the function
$$g(x,y) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}, \quad (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} $$
in polar coordinates, $x\mapsto \rho \cos\theta$ and $y\mapsto \rho \sin\theta$, to get
$$g(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta) = \frac{\rho^3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{\rho^2\cos^2\theta + \rho^4\sin^4\theta} = \frac{\rho\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta + \rho^2\sin^4\theta} $$
so I was induced to think that the limit should be $0$, since, for any $\theta$ I choose (even those that make $\cos\theta$ vanish, since they make the whole thing vanish), the rational expression should have limit $0$ as $\rho \to 0$. But then one could choose the path along the parabolic arc $P = \{(x,y)\ |\ x=y^2,\ y>0 \}$ and consider the restriction of $g$ to $P$:
$$(g|_P)(x,y) = g(y^2,y) = \frac 1 2 \quad \forall (x,y)\in P $$
which would mean the limit along the restriction is $\neq 0$ and the overall limit shouldn't exist.

*Yet*, Wolfram gives me the answer $0$ I was previously expecting. The question comes down to,

> Is my reasoning sound? If not, what am I missing? If so, what is the machine missing?

Comment: the limit doesn't exist

Comment: The problem in your reasoning is that you are fixing $\theta$ and letting $\rho \to 0$. What this essentially says is that along any line $y = \alpha x$, the limit will be zero. However, as you send $\rho \to 0$, you could also vary $\theta$ to prove that he limit doesn't exist. This is what is happening when you set $x = y^2$ for example (notice that $\theta$ changes as $(y^2,y) \to (0,0)$).

Comment: See [this very similar recent posting](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053544/wrong-wolfram-alpha-limit-lim-limits-x-y-to0-0-fracxy3x2y6) and its answer.  Bottom line: despite appearances, Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica does not actually do multivariate limits.

Comment: @User8128 Thank you. Would you care to turn this into a proper answer? I would gladly accept it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thank you too, that would answer the last question I asked

Comment: @giobrach Just submitted it as an answer. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your reasoning is that you fixed $\theta$ and then let $\rho \to 0$. When you have fixed $\theta$, you are approaching the origin along some line $\alpha x + \beta y = 0$. You're conclusion is correct: along any line through the origin, the limit is zero. However, if you let $\theta$ vary as $\rho \to 0$ (as is the case when you approach the origin along $x = y^2$, for example), then you can get a different limit. Thus the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>0$, we have 
$$f(x,\sqrt{x})=\frac{1}{2}$$

and

$$f(x,2\sqrt{x})=\frac{4}{17}$$

thus $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)\;$ doesn't exist.